# DDE SAS using VBA Commands

Tags: sas, dde

I am trying to write a code using dde in sas which would generalise my cells in excel that is previously formatted to number with 2 decimal places. I don't get any error message in the log but my excel sheet is overwritten with the code that is in the put statement that is RANGE("A1:A3").NumberFormat="General" instead of applying the format to it. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Could someone please help?

Here is my sample code,

NOTE: The Excel engine is opened before I run this code

```
filename ddeopen dde "EXCEL|System";
options noxwait noxsync;
data _null_;
   x=sleep(3);
run;
```

/* Opens the desired file in Excel*/

```
DATA _null_;
    file ddeopen;
    PUT "[OPEN(%bquote("C:\Documents and Settings\S\Desktop\test1.xls"))]";
    x=sleep(3);
run;
```

/* Format the cells to general in the opened Excel sheet*/

```
 filename ddeopen dde "EXCEL|Sheet1!r1c1:r3c1";
data _null_;
file ddeopen;
  x=sleep(3);
PUT "[%bquote(RANGE("A1:A3").NumberFormat="General")]";
RUN;
```

Many Thanks
Simi

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to select your range first using the 'R1:C1' style like so:

```
put ‘[select("r1c2:r100c2")]’;
```

Then you can format that selection with the following command:

```
put '[Format.Number("General")]';
```

This should then uses the 'General' formatting style for the cells before you export your data.